# Resizing matrix with constraints in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a 5x5 matrix that looks like this

```
A<- matrix(c(24,18,18,24,56,
         0,0,2,8,32,
         3,12,6,27,1,
         9,8,14,39,51,
         34,45,0,17,0),nrow=5,byrow=F)
```

I would like to resize it to a 2x2 that looks like this

```
C <- matrix(c(sum(A[1:2,1:2]),
          sum(A[1:2,3:5]),
          sum(A[3:5,1:2]),
          sum(A[3:5,3:5])),nrow=2,byrow = T)
```

Is there a shorter way to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't that short, but it might help a bit if you want to write a function for re-use.

Here, I note that the initial `A[1:j, 1:j]` is the first sub-matrix, and knowing `j` can determine the remaining sub-matrices.

```
j <- 2
n <- nrow(A)
p <- ncol(A)

 matrix(c(sum(A[1:j, 1:j]), sum(A[1:j, (j+1):p]), 
         sum(A[(j+1):n, 1:j]), sum(A[(j+1):n , (j+1):p])),
         nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   42  111
# [2,]  140  155
```

Comment: No worries, @hnguyen. Please click the tick mark next to the answer that helped most.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `m x m` matrix that you want to summarize into an `n x n` matrix, this would work although it is not short:

```
n = 2

#assume m x m matrix
n_row <- nrow(A)
lst = list(1:floor(n_row / n), ceiling(n_row/ n): n_row)

matrix(
  apply(expand.grid(seq_len(n), seq_len(n)),
      1,
      function(i) sum(A[lst[[i[1]]], lst[[i[2]]]])
      ),
  n)
```

Comment: Definitely less confusing than mine. Thank you!